# Unity: How to get folder in a main folder then retrieve the files?

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, directory, subdirectory

Okay so lets say we have this hierarchy: ParentFolder > ChildFolder > Files

What i want is to check whether ParentFolder exists, if it does then get the Files in ChildFolder. What i got so far is

```
string MainFolderPaths = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ParentFolder";

//Check existence of folder
if (Directory.Exists(MainFolderPaths))
{
    msgText.text = "Folder exist";

    //Returns the subdirectories in MainFolderPaths
    MainFolderDirectory = Directory.GetDirectories(MainFolderPaths);

    //Go through the folders that exist in the MainFolderDirectory
    foreach(var folder in MainFolderDirectory)
    {
         //Get the files that are in each folder
         string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folders);
         //Go through the files
         foreach(string file in files)
         {
              //read text file here
         }
    }

}
else
{
    msgText.text = "No folder found.";
}
```

**I've updated the code. I'd like to know if its right what im doing? if this is right then i could be reading file wrong.**

Comment: Well, you never told anything where to *find* `ParentFolder`. Your `MainFolderPaths` variable holds a *relative* path and you never say where to start looking.

Comment: I'm actually using` Application.persistentDataPath`

Comment: You are *now.* You weren't when I made the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where exactly is located your ParentFolder, you should add something making the path less relative. Otherwise, even if it will work in Unity Editor, it won't work in build.

You may for example write:

```
string MainFolderPaths = Application.dataPath+"/ParentFolder";
```

and then it will look for this directory in Assets (in Unity Editor) or in _Data folder (in build). More details [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html).

About getting list of subdirectories, I believe that you should use Directory.GetDirectories function described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: yes im actually using Application.persistentDataPath. However, if the method of getting the file is right then its the reading method that i messed up.